# Is JoinableQueue.join() "process safe"?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

If I have two processes communicating through a JoinableQueue, and I do the following:

process 1:

```
queue.put(1) #unfished tasks = 1
queue.join() #block until unfished tasks = 0
print('hello')
```

process 2:

```
queue.get() 
queue.task_done() #unfished tasks = 0
queue.put(1) #unfinished tasks 1
```

the unfished tasks refers to what is written in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue.join).

will 'hello' always be printed? Or is there a chance that the put in process 2 executes before process 1 noticed that it should unblock?

It seems that the whole point of join() is that 'hello' should always be printed, but I just want to make sure that I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the concrete answer:
`will 'hello' always be printed?` - No
`Or is there a chance that the put in process 2 executes before process 1 noticed that it should unblock?` - Yes

There is no guaranty, that P1 is continued (and the `join` checks the size==0) between the `task_done` and `put`. It may works, it may not, it may is random, it may difference on machines or planetary constellations -  that's called nondeterminism

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of. I'll use the suggestion in your other answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Queues should always have pure producers and pure consumers, not both. I suggest, that you use two queues. One for where P1 is producers and P2 the consumer and another vice versa.

Even not answering your question precisely, that would solve the problem i guess?

Comment: I would still just prefer an answer to the question. Also, what do you base your first sentence on? I did not read that anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: `which allows multiple producers and consumers` yes that true, but not in the sense that one process is produces and consumer at the same time. What i provided is best practice in multiprocessing. Whats the reason you want to use only one queue?

Comment: or asking differnt, do you want a theoretical understanding or do you want to solve a particular problem? What you want is maybe just a [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) for bidirectional communication?

Comment: I wanted a theoretical understanding. In principle something like this is possible: when task_done is called, a check is made if size == 0. If so, it sets a field "last_time_size_zero' with the unix time stamp (or whatever). Then when the blocked process gets some CPU time, it doesn't just check size == 0, it checks whether the last_time_size_zero happend between now and the last time it checked, and if so it unblocks

Comment: so essentially what I'm saying is, that without more details about the implementation of join(), it is not clear how it behaves. This I wanted to know

Comment: i'm afraid it's not even solved when the *implementation of join() is know*. It is the fundamental concept of parallel programming: It is not know in what order or at what time the two processes will run. And even when, the CPU is allowed the reorder the commands if they are not synchronized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248591/discussion-between-user2520938-and-tturbo).